# Hashchange only fires at the first url change

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm currently trying to use "Hashchange" but apparently, my code only fires at the first change.
How can I make it run everytime my url changes?

Note that only my url changes, I'm using the MasterPage concept with Genexus. (java servlet)

I'm aware that I can make a timer to run the code in a loop, but since the system is freaking giant, I'm afraid I should not do that.

FYI: I have absolutely zero control over the HTML.

The code I'm currently trying to fire at each change in the url.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(window).on('hashchange', function () {
        setTimeout(function(){
            $('.panel-body').find('span[class*="Readonly"]').closest('.DataContentCell').addClass('NotOpt');
        }, 1000);
    }).trigger('hashchange');
});
```

Any better approach to get the same result?
The only other idea I had was watching my body class, since it changes as well, but I can't think in a way to do that without using a timer to run the code every x seconds.

By the way, this timer in my code is irrelevant.
Thanks for the help!

Comment: Does a hashchange cause a page reload?

Comment: @bassxzero apparently, my code is making it reload the first time.
But the application by itself does not reload when changing the views.

Comment: Your code should work, here's an example: https://jsfiddle.net/zotmjxop/ . Put a `console.log` before your setTimeout to tell whether the function is being called. If it is getting called (as it should), then check an element with class `panel-body` exists and it has an `span` whit a class `Readonly` which has a parent with class `DataContentCell` which doesn't have the class `NotOpt` (I'm just rephrasing your code so you can check if you missed something)

Comment: @Pyin Hi there! It does works, but it only triggers the first time. When I change my view it does not trigger again.